# Duplicate HID report received on Mac OS 10.7

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, usb, hid

I am developing a Cocoa application that connects to a HID device for reading/writing information. I am almost done with the software which is intended to target 10.5 and 10.6, but I tried on an Mac OS X Lion 10.7 and the app gets stuck.

I have debugged and I can notice I am receiving 2 times the same report so the count of bytesReaded grows faster than it should do. This doesn't happend of earlier versions of Mac OS X.

On 10.7 I write a report for retrieving some memory address, I do receive the information so I try to read the next position, I write the report for retrieving information from the new adress but it returns the same information from the previous report, on the third read I may be able of reading the second piece of information.

I have checked for not being writing more reports than needed and it seems the writing is correct, the problem cames from the response of the device.

Any idea what can I check?

PS: Note that If I run the application having the device attached to the computer it fails, but If I run the application and the connect the device the application behaves properly.

Comment: I think I have found the bug, I have a HIDManager class which handles all the operations related with reading and writing to the HIDDevice, in this class I have a IOHIDDevice reference that I was instantiating 2 times so the report was being write twice and thats why I was receiving duplicate input reports. This behaviour doesnt happen in older versions of Mac OS X